# Javascript Code For HTML5 Canvas Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I wrote a code that doesn't work. It had a bug earlier, which was fixed. But now there is another bug: it won't draw a rectangle on the canvas. The console didn't detect the error. Here is the code:

```
13.      var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas")
14.      var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d")
15.      function getMousePos(canvas,evt){
16.          var rect=canvas.getBindingClientRect()
17.          return{
18.               x:evt.clientX-rect.left,
19.               y:evt.clientY-rect.top
20.          }
21.      }
22.      canvas.addEventListener("mouseclick",function(evt){
23.           var mousePos=getMousePos(canvas,evt)
24.           ctx.fillRect(mousePos.x-15,mousePos.y-15,10,10)
25.      },false)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
var rect=canvas.getBindingClientRect()
```

to

```
var rect=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
```

and

```
canvas.addEventListener("mouseclick",function(evt) { ...
```

to

```
canvas.addEventListener("click",function(evt) { ...
```

and it should work.

See **[ONLINE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/VSpPy/)**

Answer (score 0):

The event is `click` not `mouseclick`.